# Camera Calibration Opencv, initUndistortRectifyMap vs. Undistort

Tags: python, opencv

I've been attempting to undistort frames from a camera feed going into a Jetson AGX using Python in Visual Studio Code.

The following code got the job done, I'm just not entirely sure what is actually happening behind the scenes. OpenCV has two methods: **Undistort** and **initUndistortRectifyMap**. For some reason, the last method works perfectly, while Undistort seems to run really slowly.

Can anyone explain the big difference? I'm still pretty new to coding - thanks in advance!

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-raw, format=BGRx, width=2064, height=1544 ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw, format=BGR ! appsink")


cameramtx = np.array([[1.34120872e+03, 0.00000000e+00, 1.03042395e+03],
[0.00000000e+00, 1.34241736e+03, 8.32822269e+02],
[0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 1.00000000e+00]])


dist = np.array([[-0.30198218, 0.11819129, 0.00066535, -0.00047617, -0.025303  ]])

newcameramtx, roi = cv2.getOptimalNewCameraMatrix(cameramtx, dist, (2064,1544), 0, (2064,1544))

while True:
    _, frame = cap.read()

    mapx,mapy = cv2.initUndistortRectifyMap(cameramtx, dist, None, newcameramtx,(2064, 1544),5)
    dst = cv2.remap(frame,mapx,mapy,cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
    dst = cv2.resize(dst, (960,640))

    # dst1 = cv2.undistort(frame, cameramtx, dist, None, newcameramtx)
    # dst1 = cv2.resize(dst, (960,640))
    
    cv2.imshow('dst', dst)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break

frame.release() 
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Undistort computes the map in every call. That's why you should use initUndistortRectifyMap (once) and remap, if you care about speed and have to undistort multiple images.

Comment: Thanks Micka, I've used RectifyMap (and moved it out of the loop). Seems to run really smooth!